# How to put the same effect over multiple images but not effection the one i didn't hovered over?

Tags: html, image, css, html-table

OK. So I have 6 images in a table, 3 per row and I have 2 rows. I wanted to apply the "grow" effect to all six of my images. So I did but everything started moving every thing else in a dyslectic kind of way. Any ideas how I might do that?

CSS:

```
.raste img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.raste img:hover {
  width: 315px;
  height: 205px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
  <li>
    <a href="project1.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="log.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</td>
```

Thank you for all your answers in advance.

Comment: can you share the fiddle/code mate?

Comment: You need to provide some code, otherwise your question is unclear...

Comment: .raste img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
          transition: all 0.3s ease;
    
}
 
.raste img:hover {
  width: 315px;
  height: 205px;
  }

Comment: <td> 
      <li>
      <a href="project1.html">
      <div class="raste">
      <img src="log.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
      </div>
      </li>
      </td>

Comment: use transform:scale(1.075) or so instead resizing

Comment: @GCyrillus that's an easy solution, go ahead and write a formal answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you may use transform instead:

```
.raste img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.raste img:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.079);
          transform:scale(1.079); /*average value, set it to your needs */
}
```

Comment: @MaticToni you may need prefix-vendor, what browser(s) have you tried ?